# Error handling in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm familiar with some of the basics, but what I would like to know more about is when and why error handling (including throwing exceptions) should be used in PHP, especially on a live site or web app. Is it something that can be overused and if so, what does overuse look like? Are there cases where it shouldn't be used? Also, what are some of the common security concerns in regard to error handling?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One thing to add to what was said already is that it's paramount that you record any errors in your web application into a log. This way, as Jeff "Coding Horror" Atwood suggests, you'll know when your users are experiencing trouble with your app (instead of "asking them what's wrong").

To do this, I recommend the following type of infrastructure:

- Create a "crash" table in your database and a set of wrapper classes for reporting errors. I'd recommend setting categories for the crashes ("blocking", "security", "PHP error/warning" (vs exception), etc).
- In all of your error handling code, make sure to record the error. Doing this consistently depends on how well you built the API (above step) - it should be *trivial* to record crashes if done right.

Extra credit: sometimes, your crashes will be database-level crashes: i.e. DB server down, etc. If that's the case, your error logging infrastructure (above) will fail (you can't log the crash to the DB because the log tries to write to the DB). In that case, I would write failover logic in your Crash wrapper class to either

- send an email to the admin, AND/OR
- record the details of the crash to a plain text file

All of this sounds like an overkill, but believe me, this makes a difference in whether your application is accepted as a "stable" or "flaky". That difference comes from the fact that all apps start as flaky/crashing all the time, but those developers that know about all issues with their app have a chance to actually fix it.

Comment: Great advice whatever the platform.

Comment: Although old topic, I'd like to advise to be careful with sending an email to the admin, since many hosting services accept a limit of these and an error in a loop could cause you several trouble. Been there suffered that.

Comment: 2017+ there are now many SaaS products which help you log errors, and get notifications via Slack, email, etc. about them. Just google "error logging" and you'll find plenty, some with pretty good free tiers for startups.

Answer (score 24):

Roughly speaking, errors are a legacy in PHP, while exceptions are the modern way to treat errors. The simplest thing then, is to set up an error-handler, that throws an exception. That way all errors are converted to exceptions, and then you can simply deal with one error-handling scheme. The following code will convert errors to exceptions for you:

```
function exceptions_error_handler($severity, $message, $filename, $lineno) {
  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (error_reporting() & $severity) {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineno);
  }
}
set_error_handler('exceptions_error_handler');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

There are a few cases though, where code is specifically designed to work with errors. For example, the [`schemaValidate` method of `DomDocument`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) raises warnings, when validating a document. If you convert errors to exceptions, it will stop validating after the first failure. Some times this is what you want, but when validating a document, you might actually want *all* failures. In this case, you can temporarily install an error-handler, that collects the errors. Here's a small snippet, I've used for that purpose:

```
class errorhandler_LoggingCaller {
  protected $errors = array();
  function call($callback, $arguments = array()) {
    set_error_handler(array($this, "onError"));
    $orig_error_reporting = error_reporting(E_ALL);
    try {
      $result = call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      restore_error_handler();
      error_reporting($orig_error_reporting);
      throw $ex;
    }
    restore_error_handler();
    error_reporting($orig_error_reporting);
    return $result;
  }
  function onError($severity, $message, $file = null, $line = null) {
    $this->errors[] = $message;
  }
  function getErrors() {
    return $this->errors;
  }
  function hasErrors() {
    return count($this->errors) > 0;
  }
}
```

And a use case:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load($xml_filename);
$validation = new errorhandler_LoggingCaller();
$validation->call(
  array($doc, 'schemaValidate'),
  array($xsd_filename));
if ($validation->hasErrors()) {
  var_dump($validation->getErrors());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best practice IMHO is to use the following approach:
1. create an error/exception handler
2. start it upon the app start up
3. handle all your errors from inside there

```
<?php

class Debug {

    public static setAsErrorHandler() {
         set_error_handler(array(__CLASS__, '__error_handler'));
    }

public static function __error_handler($errcode, $errmsg, $errfile, $errline) {
       if (IN DEV) {
                print on screen
           }
           else if (IN PRO) {
                log and mail
           } 
    }
}

Debug::setAsErrorHandler();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unhanded errors stop the script, that alone is a pretty good reason to handle them.

Generally you can use a Try-Catch block to deal with errors

```
try
{
    // Code that may error
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Do other stuff if there's an error
}
```

If you want to stop the error or warning message appearing on the page then you can prefix the call with an @ sign like so.

```
 @mysql_query($query);
```

With queries however it's generally a good idea to do something like this so you have a better idea of what's going on.

```
@mysql_query($query)
    or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . '<br />Line: ' . __LINE__ . '<br />File: ' . __FILE__ . '<br /><br />');
```

Comment: Isn't using the mysql_error() function a security risk, though?

Comment: you can have a flag in your web application that determines whether you're in a test environment or in production; in production, don't show the error, just log it. In test, do both.

Comment: It's worth noting that, by default, most PHP errors won't automatically lead to an exception being thrown, which is necessary for try...catch blocks to work. You can use a method such as the one detailed at http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php to turn normal errors into exceptions.

Comment: display_errors should only be turned on in a development machine. On a live site display_errors should be off and errors should be logged to an error log. So, the @ sign is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Error Handling in cases where you don't have explicit control over the data your script is working on.  I tend to use it frequently for example in places like form validation.  Knowing how to spot error prone places in code takes some practice: Some common ones are after function calls that return a value, or when dealing with results from a database query.  You should never assume the return from a function will be what your expecting, and you should be sure to code in anticipation.  You don't have to use try/catch blocks, though they are useful.  A lot of times you can get by with a simple if/else check.

Error handling goes hand in hand with secure coding practices, as there are a lot of "errors" that don't cause your script to simply crash.  while not being strictly about error handling per se, addedbytes has a good 4 article series on some of the basics of secure PHP programming which you can find [HERE](http://www.addedbytes.com/php/writing-secure-php/).  There are a lot of other questions here on stackoverflow on topics such as [mysql_real_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysqlrealescapestring-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inject#116237) and [Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?s=regular+expressions) which can be very powerful in confirming the content of user entered data.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than outputing the mysql_error you might store it in a log. that way you can track the error (and you don't depend on users to report it) and you can go in and remove the problem.

The best error handling is the kind that is transparent to the user, let your code sort out the problem, no need to involve that user fellow.

Answer (score 1):

besides handling errors right away in your code you can also make use of

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php
and
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

I find setting your own exception handler particularly useful. When an exception occurs you can perform different operations depending on what type of exception it is.

ex: when a `mysql_connet` call returns `FALSE` I throw a `new DBConnectionException(mysql_error())` and handle it a "special" way: log the error, the DB connection info (host, username, password) etc and maybe even email the dev team notifying them that something may be really wrong with the DB

I use this to compliment standard error handling. i wouldnt recommend overusing this approach

Answer (score 1):

Error suppression with @ is very slow.

Comment: Hi Chris, a bit late, but why is that?

Comment: This is due to the way PHP is built. More on this subject: http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google Forms to catch and analyse exceptions, without having to maintain a database or publicly accessible server. There is a tutorial [here](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/articles/56351.aspx) that explains the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $error=array();
public function Errors($Err)
{

   ------ how to use -------
   $Err = array("func" => "constr", "ref"  => "constrac","context"  =>  
   "2222222ت","state" => 3,);
    $ResultErr=$this->Errors($Err);
    $context=(array_filter(explode(',', $ResultErr['context'])));
    $func=(array_filter(explode(',', $ResultErr['func'])));
    $ref=(array_filter(explode(',', $ResultErr['ref'])));
    $state=($ResultErr['state']);
    $errors=array_merge(["context"=>$context], ["func"=>$func], 
    ["ref"=>$ref], ["state"=>$state]);
    var_dump($errors);

   ---------------begine ------------------------      
    global $error;
    if (!is_array($Err)) {
        return $error;
    } else {
        if (!(isset($error['state']))) {
            $error['state']="";
        }
        if (!(isset($error['func']))) {
            $error['func']="";
        }
        if (!(isset($error['ref']))) {
            $error['ref']="";
        }
        if (!(isset($error['context']))) {
            $error['context']="";
        }
        $error['state']=$error['state'];
        $error['func']=$error['func'].= $Err["func"].",";
        $error['ref']=$error['ref'].= $Err["ref"].",";
        $error['context']=$error['context'].= $Err["context"].",";
        $error["state"]=$Err["state"];
        return $error;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem