# Php safe output

Tags: php, sanitize

When outputting user input I use this function:

```
function bbkoda($text) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($text);
    $text = nl2br($text);

    $hitta = array(
        "'\[b](.*?)\[/b]'is",
        "'\[i](.*?)\[/i]'is"
    );

    $byt = array(
        "<b>\\1</b>",
        "<i>\\1</i>"
    );

    $text = preg_replace($hitta, $byt, $text);

    return $text;
}
```

This is pretty safe right? I sanitize all i insert to db with `mysql_real_escape_string` and output it with `htmlspecialchars`. Im a very doubtful person :P

Thanks

Comment: Rather than using BB code, why not use Markdown or ReStructered text.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a quite good explanation on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysqlrealescapestring-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec) on this topic. Basically you definitely need to work on your in- and output to get it really safe!