# How to escape a string for a SQL query when you really CAN'T use parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cisco-axl

I've seen this question more than a few times obviously but haven't seen a good example of when parameterized queries truly aren't an option…but I think I have one.

I'm working with the Cisco Call Manager AXL API. Its backend is an Informix DB. Usually and whenever possible, I use the provided SOAP methods to get results, which since I'm using a WSDL-created interface class and passing parameters in actual object properties this takes care of any escaping necessary via the SOAP libraries.

However:

There are a few things I have to use direct SQL calls against the DB for, and the API provides a method where you can pass in an SQL query (as a string) and get back rows of results. Unfortunately this method doesn't provide any facility for parameterized queries. So, yes I *am actually required to do my own escaping*.

Well then, of course I could make my own regex, but A: I could easily miss something, and B: Really? There's not a utility class for this? Can I somehow use the SQL parameterization engine to spit back the escaped query? Obviously I know you have to deal with `'`, but I've read about the [backspace-character injection method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1086998/489116) and I'm sure there are others that I don't yet know about…surely someone else has already written a pretty secure version?

Scope:

- I'm interested in solutions that use off-the-shelf libraries, preferably a built-in one.
- If I have to write my own, I can use the examples in the link above and elsewhere, but I really don't want to write my own, so lets try and refrain from telling me how to do that.
- No, I can't connect directly to the Informix DB and use an Informix driver with parameterized query support. That would be a good answer, but it's ruled out in this scenario.

Comment: The backspace example you linked is about hiding a query from _humans_, not the database (that does not mean there aren't ways to trick the database, I guess that depends on the database itself).

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Quite right, looking again. I can't find the original SO question where I learned about this, but the idea I think was to pass a value that started with a backspace, e.g. `\bNULL; DROP DATABASE; --` injected into `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid = '" + sQuoteEscapedVal + "'"` would result in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE uuid = NULL; DROP DATABASE; --'`…serious air-coding there.

Answer (score 2):

You  may be able to get away with using the `EscapeSequence` class from Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll if the MsSql escaping is close enough to what your database back end uses.

You can find more information about it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.escapesequence.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET abstraction does not process quotes, it simply passes them to the underlying provider. So *if* there is an off-the-shelf library, it would be an Informix DB-specific one, but I doubt you'll find one for .NET since everyone's happy with ADO.NET or an even higher abstraction.

Even PHP, known for its `mysql_real_escape_string` function does not seem to have an equivalent for Informix DB.

Tempted to try to help solve your problem, given your scope that's all I can say.