# What are the symbols that need a special attention to enter to a database

Tags: mysql, sql

As far as I know we can't enter `'`, `"`, `\` to a database(to a `varchar` field). We need special methods like `'''`, `'"'`, `\\` to enter them into a database.

any other symbols than that?

I'm using MYSQL!

Comment: There are no such restrictions on characters in a `varchar()` field. If you're entering them as literals into the SQL statement then you'll need to escape some characters. But if you're using MYSQLI you should use prepared statements, so it's not a problem.

Comment: If you're not using a prepared statement, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and it will escape any special characters. You don't need to concern yourself with which characters are special.

Comment: If you're not using a prepared statement, you probably need your head examined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special Character Escape Sequences are listed below-
**\0** - ASCI NUL(X '00')
**\'** - Single quote (“'”)
**\"** - Double quote (“"”)
**\b** - Backspace
**\n** - Newline (linefeed)
**\r** - Carriage return
**\t** - Tab
**\Z** - ASCII 26 (Control-Z)
**\** - Backslash (“\”)
**\%** - “%”
**\_** - “_”

You can see Table 10.1 and examples to get more information on MySql's [String Literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)'s page.

Also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086918/what-characters-have-to-be-escaped-to-prevent-mysql-injections).