# MySql: SELECT where a field value contains ' and "?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve a record where the value contains single quote and double quote.

**Tried The following:**

`select * from Table1 where id = '' . ~";:><?/\!@#$%^*()_+|/ \`?' ;
`

Comment: Where's the problem? If you escape the quotes through backslashes, it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape apostrophe (') in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596652/how-to-escape-apostrophe-in-mysql)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086918/what-characters-have-to-be-escaped-to-prevent-mysql-injections) resolves it

Answer (score 3):

Use **`LIKE`** in `WHERE` clause to check whether it contains single quotes(`'`) and double quotes(`"`).

**Query**

```
select * from `your_table_name`
where `id` like '%''%'
or `id` like '%"%';
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adc321/1)**

Comment: Additional info: ANSI SQL has single quotes for strings, e.g. `'winter'`. To include a single quote, delimit it with another single quote, e.g. `'winter''s tale'`. Double quotes need no special treatment, simple include them as `'12" vinyl'`.

Comment: `like` gives me many records. But here field `id` is primary key.  it should give me a single record as output. where id = ' . ~";:><?/\!@#$%^*()_+|/ \`?

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table1 where name like "%'%" OR name like '%"%';`

Comment: `like` gives me many records. But here field `id` is primary key.  it should give me a single record as output. where id = ' . ~";:><?/\!@#$%^*()_+|/ \`?

Comment: I think you can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead of LIKE