# Why call mb_convert_encoding to sanitize text?

Tags: php, sanitization

This is in reference to [this (excellent) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysqlrealescapestring-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec/110576#110576). He states that the best solution for escaping input in PHP is to call [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) followed by [html_entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

But why exactly would you call mb_convert_encoding with the same to and from parameters (UTF8)?

Excerpt from the original answer:

> Even if you use htmlspecialchars($string) outside of HTML tags, you are still vulnerable to multi-byte charset attack vectors.
>
> The most effective you can be is to use the a combination of mb_convert_encoding and htmlentities as follows.
>
> ```
> $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
> $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
> ```

Does this have some sort of benefit I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all binary data is valid UTF8. Invoking `mb_convert_encoding` with the same from/to encodings is a simple way to ensure that one is dealing with a correctly encoded string for the given encoding.

A way to exploit the omission of UTF8 validation is described in section 6 (security considerations) in [rfc2279](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt):

> Another example might be a parser which
>   prohibits the octet sequence 2F 2E 2E 2F ("/../"), yet permits the
>   illegal octet sequence 2F C0 AE 2E 2F.

This may be more easily understood by examining the binary representation:

```
110xxxxx 10xxxxxx # header bits used by the encoding
11000000 10101110 # C0 AE
         00101110 #    2E the '.' character
```

In other words: `(C0 AE - header-bits) == '.'`

As the quoted text points out, C0 AE is not a valid UTF8 octet sequence, so `mb_convert_encoding` would have removed it from the string (or translated it to `'.'`, or something else :-).