# Security issues when cleaning arrays(in PHP)?

Tags: php, security

Could someone please explain why `$_POST= array();` isn't an effective way of resetting your $_POST superglobal?

I thought of this when reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610582/).

Being an array, I would imagine all elements of that array, be it $_POST or any other, would be reset when re-initializing it.

Comment: Maybe it's not effective because it prevents you from accessing any form input fields and effectively renders the $_POST useless?

Comment: @oggy: all depends on how you plan on using it. It's your code to type, and your logic to implement. If every action could only be used in 1 single situation, programming and scripting would lose their purpose. You mention only one of thousands of possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, `$_POST= array();` is fully resetting `$_POST`!

The answers in the other post are related to
"*how to sanitizing/clean the value(s) of `$_POST`*".

Comment: Ow, a misinterpretation on my part then.

Answer (score 1):

This line `$_POST=array();` does fully reset the `$_POST` array.

I guess there is a misunderstanding on your side of the referenced question. The goal of that script isn't to empty `$_POST` but to sanitize the values.

*tscully* tries to sanitize values in `$_POST` (because they are user-input) to be able to "safely" use them further when doing DB operations.

That's why he uses [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (Escapes special characters in a string for use in a SQL statement).

Answer (score 0):

what's exactly your question?

unset($_POST) is resetting the superglobal effectively erasing any values in it.

cross-site scripting is that wide subject you won't be able to do the filter on your own.

check this XSS cheat sheet here:
http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

+more info on developing anti-XSS measures here:
http://hungred.com/web-development/solutions-crosssite-scripting-xss-attack/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that would do it. It should be noted that this only clears out the POST information, not the GET.  The question I would have to ask is why?

Comment: Actually, this was all a misinterpretation on my part. I thought that a complete reset was what they were asking for in the other topic.