# Ways I can protect my site excluding XSS and Sql injection?

Tags: php, mysql, security, xss, sql-injection

So, members of my website can post topics, replies, comments, edit them and so on. I always use `htmlspecialchars` and `addslashes` for html inputs to protect my site against XSS and SQL injection attacks. Is it enough or is there something more I miss?
Thanks.

Comment: +1 very important question,  too bad i'm the only one that tried to answer it.  Most people get stuck and overwhelmed with the thought of xss and sqli that they don't fully realize how much can go horribly wrong.

Comment: you can stop using PHP, lol. Use Python/Django or Ruby/Rails. Their protection is turned on automatically. You don't have to care.

Comment: htmlspecialchars and addslashes will absolutely not protect you from either sql injection or xss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a lot that can go wrong with a web application.   Other than XSS and SQLi,  there is:

1. CSRF - Cross Site Request Forgery
2. LFI/RFI - Local File Include/Remote File Include caused by `include()`, `require()`...
3. CRLF injection in `mail()`
4. Global Variable Namespace Poising commonly caused by `register_globals`,`extract()`, `import_request_variables()`
5. Directory Traversal: `fopen()`, `file_get_contents()`, `file_put_conents()`
6. Remote Code Execution with `eval()` or `preg_replace()` with `/e`
7. Remote Code Execution with `passthru()`, `exec()`, `system()` and  ``

There is a whole family of vulnerabilities regarding [Broken Authentication and Session Management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management) which is apart of the [OWASP Top 10](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) that every web app programmer **must** read.

[A Study In Scarlet](http://www.securereality.com.au/studyinscarlet.txt) is a good black paper that goes over many of these vulnerabilities that I have listed.

However, there are also strange vulnerabilities like this one in [Wordpress](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2009/08/wordpress-2-8-3-admin-reset-exploit/). The definitive authority on what is a vulnerability is the [CWE system](http://cwe.mitre.org/) which classifies **HUNDREDS** of vulnerabilities,  many of which can affect web applications.

Comment: +1 for a great list and direct answer to the OP's question, although the paper itself is a bit dated (from 2001 and only discusses PHP 4).

Comment: @Justin Ethier you are correct that paper is a bit old however a lot of the "sink functions" are still problematic. I also really like the part about "language vs programmer".  It also has example vulnerable code to back my list, so I still think its relevant.

Comment: Till now the best answer. Probably you are good hacker, lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should use prepared statements (see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) to prevent SQL injection. When outputting the content htmlspecialchars() seems sufficient to prevent XSS.

Also take a look at these links for more ways to protect your site:

http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/

http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/#Listing

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main

Comment: This should be upvoted more than the one using mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: +1. PDO/mysqli is what you should use. It is much more secure (and cleaner) than having to escape everything in queries.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() is only safe in certain areas of the page and even then, only when used correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964424/to-htmlencode-or-not-to-htmlencode-user-input-on-web-form-asp-net-vb/2965444#2965444 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to protect against SQL injection is to use the `escape` function specifically written for each database - for example, for PostGreSQL use [pg_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) to escape string fields before inserting them in to the database. Or in your case, use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Even if I use `addslashes` the hacker can using SQL injection hack my site? It's not enough?

Comment: @Tom it clearly states in the documentation for addslashes that you should use the database specific escapes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: I see. But can you give me an example when using a `addslashes` function wouldn't be enough?

Comment: A quick google shows: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string I don't see why you wouldn't use the escape functions that are created for the purpose and recommended by the php documentation

Comment: I used everywhere `addslashes` instead of `mysql_escape_string`, so that's why... But probably I will have to change it.

Comment: baloo: the best reason I can think of for the resistance to switching away from addslashes() is if he's already got addslashes in dozens or hundreds of places all over his code base.  And there's a lesson there: always use *some* kind of database abstraction layer, even if it's only a handful of hand-written generic wrapper functions.  Don't sprinkle direct database-related function calls all over your code.

Comment: Yeah Frank, you are absolutely right... Good lesson, I will absolutely use it for next projects.

Comment: So then sql injection is the only vulnerability that affects web applications?  The op didn't ask how to stop sqli...

Comment: Agreed, and you put together a nice list. However, I think it is important to point out that he is using the wrong approach for preventing SQL injection. So his site is even less secure than he expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for SQL, not addslashes.
(Assuming you are using MySQL)

Comment: Even this is not a magic pill. sqli is still possible in values not delimited by single quotes. Validate data fits expected patterns and use *bound sql parameters* to guarantee injection-safety and forget about string-escaping functions.

Comment: Yes this is just one of many things in the overall security. Always design the code in a security perspective, don't wait until later

Answer (score 0):

When inserting data into database, use prepared statements. PDO are better than mysql_real_espace_string.

When displaying data, such as comments, posts, use htmlentities.

Comment: PDO and ADODB use mysql_real_espace_string() when they are connected to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

#### SQL injection:

1. No addslashes nor mysql_real_escape_string could help alone. But only when used according some rules. And even then it's not enough. So, that's why prepared statements are way better for newbies - it require no thinking.
2. Both escaping and prepared statements can help **with data only**. For the operators/identifiers there are distinct rules. (Not a big deal though - every possible combination must be hardcoded in the script)

#### XSS:

Do not allow users to use HTML.
To prevent this, both `strip_tags()` (with no allowed tags) or `htmlspecialchars()` can be used.
If you want to allow some markup, consider a BB-code use.

#### CSRF:

Any significant form must contain an unique token, which should be compared to one, saved in the session.

Comment: So then there are only 3 vulnerabilities that affect web applications?  I think you should read my post...

Comment: XSS is more complex than this, colonel. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964424/to-htmlencode-or-not-to-htmlencode-user-input-on-web-form-asp-net-vb/2965444#2965444