# How to prevent XSS in my site?

Tags: php, xss

I believe I read all the related threads appeared to me when I was writing the title.

In short, I have used almost ALL the PHP functions to sanitize the user's input, yet I still fail to stop a simple XSS test to be executed.

The code which I'm trying to secure is as follows:

```
    $keyword = $_POST['biz'];
    $keyword = strip_tags($keyword); //this
$keyword = addslashes(str_replace("||sp_rp_and||", "&", $keyword));
$keyword = addslashes(str_replace("<", "HELLO", $keyword)); //this

$myFilter = new InputFilter(); //this
$keyword = $myFilter->process($_POST['biz']); //this
if($keyword=="")
$query="select * from `business` order by business_id DESC LIMIT 0,20";
else
```

However, non of the functions does what it is supposed to do on the variable **$keyword**

Two possibilities:
*I have no what I'm doing.
*The XSS test fails, yet it doesn't mean that a person can use it to harm !!?

The test I used is simple (in the search field of th page): `">alert(document.cookie);" 
or through the URL, same result in both, a popup with the cookie shows.

What Am I doing wrong, been into this since couple of days.

P.S. Even installed Mod_security2 on server and it didn't do the job ( Or I didn't configure properly) !!

Comment: Try to output everithing that comes from the user with `htmlentities()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing server-side scripting, XSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965430/preventing-server-side-scripting-xss)

Comment: Sorry, new to this place's new posts hierarchy, Just seen this. Tried the entities as mentioned above. Please follow down.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap everything that is user-specified with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before outputting it.

Comment: @ma2moun: What is the problem, exactly? You need to add it _only_ when outputting data.

Comment: What do you mean when outputting the data ?

Comment: @ma2moun: Aren't you displaying this data anywhere on your page? You do not need to escape anything for internal use.

Comment: But my data is alphanumeric ONLY, why should I allow html input then ?

Comment: @ma2moun: This function does not validate input. It makes sure that output is XSS-safe. And that was what you asked for, right?

Comment: Maybe sanitize is the word ? splitting tags ?removing unnecessary input ?

Comment: @ma2moun: Sanitizing data has nothing to do with XSS, really. It is much easier to escape the user-specified data when it is outputted. It _is_ XSS-safe then.

Comment: @elusive right sorry about the confusion, I'm quite frustrated right here and things are getting complicated. So far, function on both output and input, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, str_replace, etc... the problem is that none is giving any sort of results AT ALL. I'm sure this due to my wrong implementation, so what I'm after right now is which variable to be wrapped into htmlspecialchars() for instance ?

Comment: @ma2moun: None of them needs to be wrapped in your internal code. You need to wrap every variable you're outputting that is somehow filled with user-defined content. That is the only place where this is needed.

Comment: @ma2moun: when you output any text in HTML, even text *you* expect to be alphanumeric, you have to escape it with `htmlspecialchars()`. It doesn't enable HTML in the string — it *disables* interpretation of text as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you're doing all that hard work processing the the form, and then loosing it a few moments later

Here you've done some processing to $_POST['biz']:

```
$keyword = $_POST['biz'];
    $keyword = strip_tags($keyword); //this
$keyword = addslashes(str_replace("||sp_rp_and||", "&", $keyword));
$keyword = addslashes(str_replace("<", "HELLO", $keyword)); //this
```

And here you set it equal to something else entirely:

`$keyword = $myFilter->process($_POST['biz']); //this`

Its possible that line should instead be:

`$keyword = $myFilter->process($keywork);`

Comment: I refined the code to include one function at at time, meaning that I used htmlspecialchars() once on $keyword, no results, str_replace(), same, htmlentities(), same ! 
 [code]$keyword = $_POST['biz'];
 $keyword = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($keyword)); //this
 $keyword = htmlentities($keyword, ENT_QUOTES); //this [/code]