# Should I sanitize EVERY form variable passed along?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, security

I have a form with many fields...

The action is set to a php page which queries mysql...

Should I sanitize with `mysql_real_escape_string` every single variable?
Or can I ignore sanitizing drop-lists and radios for instance?

Also, besides `mysql_real_escape_string`, what else should I do to prevent attacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must check selects and radio buttons too. Anyone can create their own HTML form and post it to your script. The Firefox extension *Web Developer Toolbar* even has an option to convert selects to text inputs.

You can also check that the posted data only contains correct values. For example, if you have a radio button, make sure that the posted form only contain one of the valid values.

You should of course only run mysql_real_escape_string on variables that you are going to put into MySQL. If saving to file, using on the commandline or anything other, there are more apropriate functions and solutions.

Comment: remember mysql_real_escape_string is only safe to use when the escaped value is delimited by single quotes in the resultant sql statement. Even better: forget about string escaping and just use bound sql parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In general it is trivial to form a POST request outside of the browser and so bypass any restrictions the drop down list (for example) may have imposed on possible values.

Because of this you should always treat user data as hostile and error-prone and put as much validation and protection on the server-side as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Another bunch of ignorant answers. Camran, you're attracting it like magnet.

You have to understand that mysql_real_escape_string **has nothing to do** with forms and radios, with checking and sanitizing.
And it does not prevent attacks.

It is merely a string escaping function. It escapes a data that going to be inserted into SQL query string as a string data.

SQL query is a little program. With it's own syntax. You **must** follow that syntax, not because of "attacks" but because of it's just a syntax. And, of course, these rules do not depend on the source of data! Radio button, html form or browser - all doesn't matter!

And it works only with strings. Not with numbers nor identifiers.

Here is my answer on how to handle an SQL query:
[In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape strings prior to using them in SQL statements, to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

In addition, when taking data out of your database and writing it out as HTML, you should consider using [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Better to use htmlspecialchars() I think. strip_tags is not always working as intended.

Comment: neither htmlspecialchars nor mysql_real_escape_string work as a magic pill under all conditions, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec

Answer (score 1):

Any variable sent from the client can't be consider as safe and valid. If you are using them in query you should always sanitize them.

Comment: what about variables that weren't sent from the client?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to sanitize the fields that you don't want an attacker to hijack.  The data can be form any source, not just your page.  `mysql_real_escape_string` is good for any value that will concatenated into a query, but I "sanitize" everything.  To me, "sanitize" means more than handling injection attacks, it includes any field validation as well (sting length, numeric, valid date, empty, etc).