# Inserting text from textarea into MySQL database without losing formatting

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add text from a textarea on my site into a MySQL database.

Below is the PHP code that is adding the text to the database.

```
if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $text = sanitizeString($_POST['text']);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'";
    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)))
    {
        queryMysql("UPDATE profiles SET text='$text' where user='$user'");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO profiles VALUES('$user', '$text')";
        queryMysql($query);
    }

}
else
{
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'";
    $result = queryMysql($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row  = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $text = stripslashes($row[1]);
    }
    else $text = "";
}

$text = stripslashes(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $text));
```

And below is the code of the form.

```
<textarea name='text' cols='40' rows='3'>$text</textarea><br />
```

But when the data is inputted, it shows it in the database correct but not showing it displayed properly. See the images below:

*The text that is entered*

[image: the text that is entered]

*How the text is displayed on the page*

[image: this is how the text is displayed]

*How the text is in the database*

[image: this is the text in the database]

This is the PHP code that displays the text on the page.

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />
```

Hope you can help!!

EDIT: added extra php code

Comment: I hope that `sanitizeString` actually runs `mysql_real_escape_string`, otherwise you're running a high risk of SQL injection. And what do you exactly mean by “not showing it displayed properly”? I see two textareas with correct white spaces. How do you display that text?

Comment: The full code for adding text is above now. Where should I put `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: `stripslashes`? Why do you need that? And what does `sanitizeString` do?

Comment: The code wasn't written by me. It was written by a colleague and I am styling the site for him. I would like to add Markdown in the future. How would I go about adding this?

Comment: That's a completely different question. A search here and on Google will reveal a lot. But please tell you colleague to learn a few things about security (point him to XSS and SQL injection). That will save you and your customers a lot of trouble.

Comment: OK I will... So when I display the text I don't need `echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=left /><br />`? Just `echo ($row[1])`?

Also about the SQL injection worry, How do I run `sanitizeString` through `mysql_real_escape_string`?

Comment: It depends: if there are unwanted slashes in your text, you'll have to strip them (but how did they creep into the input, that would be a better issue to deal with: to solve the actual problem). If you want to output text to an HTML page, use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS attacks. And again: what does `sanitizeString` do now? To prevent SQL injection, you'll have to either use `mysql_real_escape_string` to properly escape your input or, better, use parametrized queries. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575//110576#110576) and its comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your text, unless you're using a rich-text editor, such as Mark-down (as here on Stackoverflow), is styled by your CSS, not by the contents of the `textarea` itself.

If the problem is preservation of new-lines, then you could run the string through the [`nl2br($text)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function before storing in, or retrieving from, the database.

I'd suggest on retrieval would be better, but that's just my opinion (and I can't offer any evidence to back it up).

Comment: I ended up moving over to Ruby on Rails, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're absolutely welcome! Thanks for the accept, and I'm glad that you find a means to your end.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use

```
echo nl2br($test);
```