# PHP - Make button click send textarea content to table

Tags: php, string, button, onclick, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting text from textarea into MySQL database without losing formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863320/inserting-text-from-textarea-into-mysql-database-without-losing-formatting)

Can anybody tell me how to make the submit button submit the content of the textarea to a table? I know it is some very simple problem, but unfortunately i've been unable to find any solution for days.

**This is the code:**

```
  <div class="textareawrapper">
<textarea name="reddilemma" Class="redtext" rows="4" cols="30" onclick="this.value = firstToUpper(this.value)" value="$reddata"></textarea>
<textarea name="bluedilemma" Class="bluetext" rows="4" cols="30" onclick="this.value = firstToUpper(this.value)"></textarea>

      </div>
    <input type="submit" Class="submit" />

<?PHP

$user_name = "blabla";
$password = "blablabla";
$database = "blabla_database";
$server = "localhost";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
$reddata = $_post['reddilemma'];
$bluedata = $_post['bluedilemma'];

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "INSERT INTO dilemma_id (reddilemma, bluedilemma) VALUES ('$reddata', '$bluedata')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

mysql_close($db_handle);

print "";
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

Comment: You could try this existing answer I found by Googling "php submit textarea to mysql": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863320/inserting-text-from-textarea-into-mysql-database-without-losing-formatting

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

PHP variable names are [case sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), you want to access `$_POST` not `$_post`, so try this:

```
$reddata = $_POST['reddilemma'];
$bluedata = $_POST['bluedilemma'];
```

Comment: The thing is, that the button isn't even connected to the PHP code. I'm not aware of how to do that.

Comment: You need to enclose your `<textarea>` in a `<form>` tag, which in the `action` attribute you to tell what php file to send the form data to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your elements with `<form>` tag to submit data.