# I want my search to only show results with matching field values. How is this done?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want my search to only display results that match values in the same row.

I have two search fields:

'search' and 'search term'

the field names in my database are

name
lastname
email

So for example:

If i search

'mike' in 'search' and 'smith' in 'search term' the only results I want to show are results that match 'mike smith' NOT showing results like 'mike harris'

How is this achieved?

Thanks!

James

```
 <?php

$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "");



if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$search = addcslashes($search,'%_');
$searchterm = addcslashes($searchterm,'%_');

  $search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";



if (!mysql_select_db("")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$search = $_POST['search'];
$searchterm = $_POST['searchterm'];
$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email
FROM   test_mysql
WHERE  name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($search) ."%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if(empty($_GET['search'])){ // or whatever your field's name is
  echo 'no results';
}else{
  performSearch(); // do what you're doing right now
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<br><br><div class="data1">';
echo htmlentities($row["name"]);
echo '</div><br><div class="data2">';
echo htmlentities($row["lastname"]);
echo '</div><br><div class="data3">';
echo htmlentities($row["email"]);
echo '</div>';
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Comment: This question reads funny since your example is doing nothing with $searchterm. I assume you already tried a simple AND statement? "WHERE name LIKE '%".$search."%' AND name LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'" - which would make both words a requirement.

Comment: Sorry i am very new to mysql i only started yesterday. How do I fit that around the mysql_real_escape_string($search) ? I am learning the syntax and am unsure how to layout what you just said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
WHERE  name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($search) ."%'";
```

To:

```
WHERE  name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($search) ."%' AND lastname LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($search) ."%'";
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for! How can i stop the search returning all the database's results when an empty query is sent?

Comment: You would check the $search and $searchterm variable before running the code: `if($search === '' && $searchterm === '') { ... do something here ... } else { run query }`. Keep in mind people can send in a % symbol which will also match everything, don't know if that is a problem for you.

Comment: Oh how can it be stopped so they can't return everything if they send '%'

Comment: Stop using `LIKE`? Do you really need it? Or: `$search = addcslashes($search, '%_');` (and the same for `$searchterm`). This will add a backslash so that MySQL will interpret it as a literal and not a wildcard.

Comment: Sorry I have only been using mysql since yesterday so by saying don't use LIKE is it just a matter of putting a different word there instead of LIKE?

Comment: You can use `=` to do an exact compare. But I can't really teach you SQL in comment boxes.

Comment: Ah yeah! I updated the code in my question with what you just said. It still returns all the results when i enter '%' in the search field. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I have no room to add the answer in this comment box, so I added another answer, so check it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email
FROM   test_mysql
WHERE  name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($search) ."%'
AND name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($searchterm) ."%'";
```

Additionally, as I look over your query you may want to consider matching against last name as well. Your example suggested you may be looking for a first and last name, yet the query is only comparing name.

I often create a field called "search" in my searchable tables then set them as full text index so I can use mysql MATCH AGAINST for a more robust search option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

It was a while into my php development before I learned about match against. Certainly would have been beneficial to know early on. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just the answer I needed! How can i stop the search returning all the database's results when an empty query is sent?

Comment: a conditional statement before processing. if(!empty($_POST['search'])){ your code here } ... but you may want to get more complex, like using php trim($_POST['search']) to ensure it's not just white space. or strlen($_POST['search']) to make sure it's more than one character. etc.

Comment: Thanks, are there any good sites you know that would help a mysql beginner?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$search = addcslashes($search,'%_');
$searchterm = addcslashes($searchterm,'%_');

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";
```

To:

```
$search = "%" . addcslashes($_POST["search"],'%_'). "%";
$searchterm = "%" . addcslashes($_POST["searchterm"],'%_'). "%";
```

Comment: Thanks Ariel! i really appreciate all your help. Please check out http://www.weezy.co.uk/newresults.php search '%' in the search field. Why does the right column disappear?

Comment: Because you did "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting" - i.e. you exited instead of skipping the row display, but continuing.

Comment: Ah thanks, i got rid of that part and it works fine now. Another issue I keep facing is that i am difficulty making it so no results show up when an empty search is submitted? I have used samples but i really am unsure of how to make it work

Comment: @James Sorry, but this is more than is practical in this medium. You need to learn more programming. Instead of you learning things I am just feeding you code.

Comment: Are there any books/sites you recomend for mysql beginners?