# Is mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars()) really useful ? why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security

Is it really usefull to have something like :

```
$passe = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe']));
```

why do we use this?
how to optimize it ?

Thank you

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("nom_db");

$passe = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe']));
$passe2 = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe2']));
if($passe == $passe2)
{
    script here
}

else
{
    echo 'Your password is wrong';
}
?>
```

Comment: In the code you show, both functions are completely unnecessary. I suspect that that's not the only place where those variables are used, is it? Can you show a more verbose example?

Comment: This may be relevant: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: @Pekka : I had a doubt about it, it was not logical for me.
http://pastebin.com/rJbWmm7m

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-injec

Answer (score 6):

In that code example, it isn't useful at all.

`htmlspecialchars` converts characters with special meaning in HTML into entities. That is essential if you have some text that you want to insert into an HTML document (as it stops, for instance, characters such as `<` being treated as the start of tags, and protects against [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

`mysql_real_escape_string` converts characters with special meaning in MySQL SQL queries into escapes. This allows you to insert arbitrary strings into a MySQL database safely (protecting against errors and [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). There are, however, [better ways to do the same thing](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

In this case, you are just comparing two strings. Running them through a bunch of conversions isn't going to do anything useful.

Comment: Good answer. Using both functions is not just pointless, it can be even harmful. Double escaping can make it impossible to give out a correct output later. Escaping should be done as late as possible, and only for the given target system.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `mysql_real_escape_string($var)` when passing untrusted variables in to a database query like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `bar` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'");
```

It is important to do this to protect against [SQL injection attacks](http://www.bobbytables.com).

As for `htmlspecialchars()`, this should be used when *outputting* untrusted variables to page, it will strip out any HTML to prevent an variable outputting unwanted or dangerous HTML on top a page (javascript for example).

In your example, you need neither functions as you are just comparing them and are not putting them in a database or on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Using `htmlspecialchars()` like you is pointless, because for strings:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe'])) == 
    mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe2']));
```

Is as equal as:

```
$_POST['passe'] == $_POST['passe2']
```

Comment: Its true yeah, i didn't think about it

Comment: @sanmai, this is not exactly true - for example if $_POST['passe'] is array and $_POST['passe2'] is empty string,NULL or different array, then $_POST['passe'] == $_POST['passe2'] will return false and mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe'])) == mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passe2'])) will return true(with warning, but it will), but I agree that it is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Using Of htmlspecialchars  keep you protected from xss but there is bypass method
if you will add this word to url

like

`  link name ' ;

bypass  will use  javascript  onmouseout onhover  else   That require magic_qutoes off

---

addslashes & mysql_real_escape_string   protect from sql injection

by ignore the `'` or `"` quotes

but the good way to remove this words after make it in lowercase

mean
 $username = strtolower($_GET['ser']);
 if(preg_match("(select|and|or|union|into|from|information|schema|.user|concat|group)\", $username)){
 die("Error : Hacking Attemp ");
}

Comment: Hi SamarLover, what exactly do strolower()?
Do we have to combine addslashes() & mysql_real_escape_string() with strtolower()?

Comment: Hello Zeroth , strtolower will make all work in small letters , and you can use only one from addslashes and mysql_real_escape_string  but strtolower you should use it if you will use your own function beacuse when you check the input like ( Union Select etc) and you told your function to remove union and select it will not remove the injection words because its not the same letters , or use php Regx

Answer (score 0):

Your full code in the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rJbWmm7m) shows that the variables are used later for a database query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO validation VALUES('', '$pseudo', '$passe', '$email')");
```

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is a **must** here; `htmlspecialchars` isn't, for the reasons @Quentin explained so well above.

Use `htmlspecialchars` later in the output if anything of what you insert gets output on a HTML page.

Comment: NICE, what's happen now if i have a form who allow people to write a text. do i use a textarea ? and which protectino i have to setup ?
- protect html
- protect jvascript
?