# Why do I get a syntax error when embedding array elements in a string?

Tags: php, sql, post, insert

I am trying to INSERT some data into a database.  I can do this on one FIELD just not on multiple.  It seems to be a simple syntax issue.  The error I get is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
```

The error is on the INSERT line:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("local","username","password");
if (!$con)
{die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_select_db("npsreviews", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO burkett (DATE, STORE, 5STAR, 4STAR, 3STAR, 2STAR, 1STAR, TOTAL, NPS) VALUES ('$_POST[DATE]', '$_POST[STORE]', '$_POST[5STAR]', '$_POST[4STAR]', '$_POST[3STAR]', '$_POST[2STAR]', '$_POST[1STAR]', '$_POST[TOTAL]', '$_POST[NPS]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Thanks in advance, I cannot find the answer when looking for Multiple $POST.

Comment: What is a "multiple $_POST"?  Can you explain more?  Are you talking about `$_POST` values that are arrays?  Also, please read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), a vulnerability that your code suffers from.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'$_POST["3STAR"]'`, etc?

Comment: Your are opening yourself to *hilariously* awful SQL injection. Throw this entire block of code out, it is *absolutely unsalvageable*, and start over using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Whatever tutorial you've used to produce this code is terribly out of date.

Comment: @Charles I am VERY new to php and sql sorry for the confusion.  I meant simply I need to POST all that data, so I assumed I say multiple times.

Comment: @meager http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php for part of it

Comment: @ToddN It is possible to produce safe (if dated) code with the `mysql_` family of functions, but you shouldn't. Use PDO. If you're learning something new either way, you might as well learn the *modern* equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're missing quotes around the array indices; It should be `$_POST["STORE"]`, not `$_POST[STORE]`. Secondly, you can't index arrays this way with string interpolation. You'll need to use `{$...}` syntax:

```
$x = array("key" => "value");

echo "The value of 'key' is '{$x["key"]}'";
```

Or concatenate the pieces of the string:

```
echo "The value of 'key' is '" . $x["key"] . "'";
```

Either method will produce:

```
The value of 'key' is 'value'
```

---

Note: I've answered your question as a simple syntax error, but this does *not* solve your real problem, which is rampant SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Ok ill look into that as well, this is to be used as an internal database.

Comment: The simplest, not the best, solution to the injection problem would be to use the second format (concatenate) and `mysql_real_escape_string()` functions. Thus `echo "the value of 'key' is '" . mysql_real_escape_string($x["key"]) . "'";`

Answer (score 1):

SQL query should look like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO burkett (DATE, STORE, 5STAR, 4STAR, 3STAR, 2STAR, 1STAR, TOTAL, NPS) VALUES ('{$_POST["DATE"]}', 
'{$_POST["STORE"]}', '{$_POST["5STAR"]}', '{$_POST["4STAR"]}', '{$_POST["3STAR"]}', '{$_POST["2STAR"]}', 
'{$_POST["1STAR"]}', '{$_POST["TOTAL"]}', '{$_POST["NPS"]}')";
```

But in all your SQL query is prone to **SQL Injection** so I would recommend to clean your POST before doing something with it

read more about SQL injections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje/110576#110576)

You can clean your $_POST using this

```
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$_POST);
```

Or use PDO and use prepared statements to accomplish sql INSERTS, UPDATES etc

Comment: Thank you Jaspreet for the link.

Comment: No Probs. Just letting you know that PDO is by far the best way you can go about writing queries for mysql using php. Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

escape it as so:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO burkett (DATE, STORE, 5STAR, 4STAR, 3STAR, 2STAR, 1STAR, TOTAL, NPS) VALUES ('" . $_POST['DATE'] . "', '" . $_POST['STORE'] . "', '" . $_POST['5STAR'] . "', '" . $_POST['4STAR'] . "', '" . $_POST['3STAR'] . "', '" . $_POST['2STAR'] . "', '" . $_POST['1STAR'] . "', '" . $_POST['TOTAL'] . "', '" . $_POST['NPS'] . "')";
```