# Confused on htmlspecialchars, real_escape_string, etc

Tags: php, mysql, security

I've written a decent admin interface that includes inventory management, content management, and blogging. Now its time to lock it down and make it secure (Yes, I should have been doing it from the beginning...

For blog creation/editing, I'm using ckeditor which posts HTML output to editblog.php. Also i'm using simple text inputs for Title, Author, etc...

I'm concerned because the blog will have img src="uploads/etc.jpg", as well as divs, spans, etc...

SO! When I sanitize this data, how do I make sure that all those quotes and slashes can be safely shoved into my SQL database, and what do i do to spit it back out on the frontend? I'm also concerned because if the blogger "quotes" something, I don't want that to be messed with either.

Simple input like title, author, etc I'm using $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($title)
But is that enough? How do I preserve the user's intended input while avoiding attack?

I've done my research and yet I still don't get it. I hope someone can break it down nice and simple for me...

Answer (score 1):

Nice and simple...

**You always sanitize for the context to which you want to write.**

These techniques will preserve the user's input, but prevent that input from being interpreted as code within a specific context.

When you want to query the database, you are worried about SQL injection attacks:

- Use mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize SQL for the database query.

When you want to display something (as HTML) that will be parsed by the browser, you are worried about cross site scripting:

- Use htmlspecialchars to sanitize for HTML output.

This will provide a basic level of security.

- For more security on the database side, you should look at **prepared statements** and PHP **PDO**.
- For more information about some pitfalls of htmlspecialchars, take a look at @Cheekysoft's excellent explaination: [htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje)