# MySQL in PHP: Always returns 0 rows exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute a MySQL query in PHP but I am having some problems. It appears that when running this query in PHP it always returns 0 rows, but running this in my console works as expected.

```
<?php
include '../mysql.php';
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE name = '" . $name . "' AND email = '" . $email . "'";
echo $sql . "</br>";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if(!$res) {
    die("Query Failed!");
}
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.</br>", $row_cnt);
if($row_cnt > 0) {
    echo "Account exists!";
} else {
    echo "Account does not exist! Creating...</br>";
    if(mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO accounts (`name`, `email`, `password`, `ip`) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', 'abc123', 'localhost')")) {
        echo "Created account!";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to create account";
    }
}
mysqli_free_result($res);
mysql_close($connection);
```

The output:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE name = 'testUser' AND email = 'abc123@gmail.com'
Result set has 0 rows.
Account does not exist! Creating...
Created account!
```

Then in the table we see the expected:

```
mysql> select * from accounts;
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | name     | email            | password | ip        |
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| 10 | testUser | abc123@gmail.com | abc123   | localhost |
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when the query is ran again it has the same exact output and another row is created.

```
mysql> select * from accounts;
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| id | name     | email            | password | ip        |
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
| 10 | testUser | abc123@gmail.com | abc123   | localhost |
| 11 | testUser | abc123@gmail.com | abc123   | localhost |
+----+----------+------------------+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas on why it cannot detect that the data exists in a row already?

Comment: You're using `SELECT count(*)` then checking the row count, this will never work.  You need to get the value of the first (count) column which will be the number of rows matching your conditions.

Comment: imo, since you are certain to get one row back with a count it. Then just fetch it anyway. The `num_rows` count tells you nothing useful. It rarely tells you anything useful since you want the data and then process it. Assume you will get some data. So always fetch it. You test for the end of it anyway. i.e. `num_rows` is rarely useful when used with `select` queries. imo.

Comment: Hash your passwords if you care about your data. Protect from sql injection. Some apps are throw-away apps, sure, and they don't count.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different variables, $result and $res.
Change this:

```
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
```

To:

```
$row_cnt = $res->num_rows;
```

**UPDATE:**

Also change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE name = '" . $name . "' AND email = '" . $email . "'";
```

To:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name = '" . $name . "' AND email = '" . $email . "'";
```

Otherwise your $res will always be equal to one and so application will not behave as expected.
 – Devon

**UPDATE #2:**

Close connection with

```
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Instead

```
mysql_close($connection);
```

Don't mix these two!! – Saty

**UPDATE #3**

Read about cleaning PHP variables to protect your application. One good post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje/110576#110576) and plenty more available on google.

Comment: Except, because of using the aggregate function count in `SELECT count(*)` this will always  return 1 whether there are 0 rows matching the conditions or 1000 rows matching the conditions.

Comment: There are 2 problems, but this is definitely an answer to one of them.

Comment: No, it will not... The row count will always be 1 when doing select count without grouping, regardless of the query.

Comment: @K.I I think you're missing what Devon is pointing out. SELECT COUNT will _always_ return at least 1 row.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry! Stupid me! It will always be = 1. Updated my answer.

Comment: Add one more thing close connection with `mysqli_close($connection);` instead `mysql_close($connection);` don't mix these two!!

Comment: Plus also add some information about sql injection!!