# Delete post using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to $.ajax and don't know so much and i have following button to delete user post by article ID

```
<button type="button" onclick="submitdata();">Delete</button>
```

When click this button then following $.ajax process running.

```
<script>
    var post_id="<?php echo $userIdRow['post_id']; ?>";
    var datastring='post_id='+post_id;
    function submitdata() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"delete.php",
            data:datastring,
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

And delete.php is

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include 'conn.php';
$dbClass = new Database();
// confirm that the 'post_id' variable has been set
if (isset($_GET['post_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['post_id'])) {
// get the 'post_id' variable from the URL
    $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];

// delete record from database
    if ($userPostsQuery = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare("DELETE FROM user_posts WHERE post_id = :post_id")) {
        $userPostsQuery->bindValue(":post_id", $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $userPostsQuery->execute();
        $userPostsQuery->close();
        echo "Deleted success";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }

}
?>
```

This code not working post not deleted. Please how do I do?

Comment: `var post_id="<?php echo $userIdRow['post_id']; ?>";`  i am sure for each record id will be different. so this code will not always give you correct id  and `$_GET` need to be change to `$_POST`

Comment: for a POST, use $_POST ... $_GET is for GET

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call, look at the network request, look at the server logs. Somewhere you should have an error message that tells you the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want to not only match the "GET" you use in your PHP but also add the ID to the button

```
<button class="del" type="button" 
  data-id="<?php echo $userIdRow['post_id']; ?>">Delete</button>
```

using $.get which matches your PHP OR use `$.ajax({ "type":"DELETE"`

```
$(function() {
  $(".del").on("click", function() {
    $.get("delete.php",{"post_id":$(this).data("id")},
       function(html) {
            alert(html);
       }
    );
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** Please clean the var

[Do htmlspecialchars and mysql_real_escape_string keep my PHP code safe from injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje/110576#110576)

**Using ajax DELETE with error handling**

```
$(function() {
  $(".del").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "delete.php",
      method: "DELETE", // use "GET" if server does not handle DELETE
      data: { "post_id": $(this).data("id") },
      dataType: "html"
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      $( "#log" ).html( msg );
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    }); 
  });
});
```

In the PHP you can do

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') {
  $id = $_REQUEST["post_id"] ....
}
```

Comment: +10. because it's correct rather than others. It raised same points what i have raised in my comment

Comment: despite JS part which is good, using POST to delete does not look good for me.

Comment: Why not? You could do DELETE I guess but that is not supported by jQuery

Comment: because http specification says that POST is used to create new resource also POST is non idempotent that's why DELETE is the best option but still GET is better than POST. On the other hand GET is considered as "safe" method so... there's no better option than DELETE :P https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Updated to include type=DELETE

Comment: Need i change $_GET['post_id'] to $_POST['post_id'] in delete.php?

Comment: i am using your code then nothing happen. Article didn't deleted. In console nothing to show

Comment: this code has one literal mistake `"post_id` here you forgot `"`

Comment: Can you show the complete html  in http://pastebin.com/ also the php where you get the post_id

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: post_id in delete.php on line 9

Comment: it is on line $_REQUEST["post_id"]

Comment: how do i fix undefined index post_id?

Comment: Can you do print_r($_REQUEST); in delete.php and add a <div id="log"></div> tou your page to handle  `$( "#log" ).html( msg );`

Comment: i created <div id="log"></div> and that's why i can see which error occurs. print_r result is "Array ( ) "

Comment: and if you change method: "DELETE", to "GET" ? Your server has to accept the DELETE

Comment: it works now! Changed method to "GET" as you said.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason is pretty simple. You should change your request type to GET/DELETE instead of POST. In PHP you expect GET request but in AJAX you send POST request

Change:

```
type:"POST",
url:"delete.php",
data:datastring,
```

to

```
type:"DELETE",
url:"delete.php?" + datastring,
```

in PHP

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE' && !empty($_REQUEST["post_id") {
    $id = $_REQUEST["post_id"];
   // perform delete
}
```

DELETE is actually the only valid method to delete objects. POST should create an object and GET should retrieve it. It may be confusing at first time but it's good practicet specially used in REST APIs. The other one would be UNLINK if you wanted to remove relationship between objects.

Comment: maybe you should suggest him to change PHP code and use POST instead. Operations such as delete should not be made with GET method.

Comment: should not be done with POST either. The best method for it is DELETE. And GET work more similar to DELETE than POST

Comment: Depends on the API specifications, but you are right. DELETE is suggested method.

Comment: Because of your name it looks like I'd be talking to myself

Comment: i edited all code in your said but article didn't deleted and nothing happen. in console no errors to show

Comment: open browser console go to network filter by XHR request and see the response if there are any errors

Answer (score 1):

since you're sending a post request with ajax so you should use a $_POST iin your script and not a $_GET
here is how it sould be

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include 'conn.php';
$dbClass = new Database();
// confirm that the 'post_id' variable has been set
if (isset($_POST['post_id']) && is_numeric($_POST['post_id'])) {
// get the 'post_id' variable from the URL
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

// delete record from database
    if ($userPostsQuery = $dbClass::Connect()->prepare("DELETE FROM user_posts WHERE post_id = :post_id")) {
        $userPostsQuery->bindValue(":post_id", $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $userPostsQuery->execute();
        $userPostsQuery->close();
        echo "Deleted success";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }

}
?>
```

> for the JS code

```
<script>
    var post_id="<?php echo $userIdRow['post_id']; ?>";
    function submitdata() {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"delete.php",
            data:{"post_id":post_id},
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                alert(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

here i've supposed thqt the  give you the real id post you're looking for !!

Comment: @user3227899 you can check my edit now hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Follow @roberts advise and also:

You should have a way to handle errors eg.

to your ajax code add this:

```
    error:function(e){
     alert(e.statusText)// if you like alerts
     console.log(e.statusText)// If you like console
   }
```

You should also check your error logs. Assuming you use apache2 and linux
execute this in terminal:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

This gives you a very elaborate way to code. You also eliminate the problem of trial and error.