# What is the steps to Validate entered URL, Its safety and prevent XSS attacks?

Tags: php, validation, url, xss

For a form like this

```html
<form method='post' action=''>
    <input type='url' name='urlink'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

How to validate any entered `URL` and be sure that it is **safe** to be used in the element

`<embed>, <frame>, <iframe>, <source>, <img>`

What i do is the following steps

```
<?php 
    $url = $_POST['urlink'];
    $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    $url = preg_replace('#((https?|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i',"'<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\">$3</a>$4'", $url);

    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) && preg_match('/(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/", $url)){
        echo "SAFE URL";
    } else {
        echo "UNSAFE URL";
    } 
?>
```

Is that enough for it to be sure that the `URL` is safe?

Comment: No it's not enough, have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110575/do-htmlspecialchars-and-mysql-real-escape-string-keep-my-php-code-safe-from-inje) for a more extensive solution.

Comment: Safe URL for what? It clearly depends on what you want to do with the data you receive from the client.

Comment: @Progman safe to be used in the `elements` i wrote `<embed>, <frame>, <iframe>, <source>, <img>`

Comment: @MinistryofChaps I use PDO, But my concern is about using the `URLs` inside the HTML `elements`, So i would like to ask, does turning the special characters to HTML entities prevents any special characters from being executed while showing the `elements`?

Comment: @AXAI the ticked answer also covers that.